# Linear coefficient of chromatic polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, chromatic-polynomial

I am interested in the combinatorics of the linear coefficient of the chromatic polynomials. I have the following questions.

1. What are some class of graphs for which it is possible to calculate this number explicitly? For example, Trees, Complete graph, and Cycles. How to calculate this number in general?
2. What are some interesting combinatorics of this number?

Kindly share some references.

Thank you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009611/lowest-coefficient-of-chromatic-polynomial and around.

Comment: Seeing the chromatic polynomials of trees, complete graphs and cycles are known, finding the linear term is not so hard. As @user64495 has linked to, the best combinatorial interpretation is that the linear term is the number of acyclic orientations with a single source vertex.

Comment: To clarify, "a single source vertex" means that for any fixed vertex $v$, the linear term (up to sign) is the number of acyclic orientations with single source vertex $v$. It is not *a priori* clear that this number is independent of $v$,

Comment: @RichardStanley Indeed - I knew what I meant, but what I actually wrote was not very precise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your comments were helpful and lead to some good references.